# Converting year-month to next year-quarter

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime

I have below date expressed as yearmon '`202112'`

I want to convert this to yearqtr and report the next quarter. Therefore from above string I want to get `2022Q1`

I unsuccessfully tried below

```
import pandas as pd
pd.PeriodIndex(pd.to_datetime('202112') ,freq='Q')
```

Could you please help how to obtain the expected quarter. Any pointer will be veru helpful

Comment: Does the data exist in a dataframe and you want to convert a column formatted in YYYYMM to YYYYQ? Is January represented as 1 or 01?

Comment: Source is `string` object. January represents 01

Comment: Since we are only calculating quarters, you can just append the date `pd.to_datetime('202112' + "01").to_period('Q') + 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think one issue you're running into is that `'202112'` is not a valid date format. You'll want to use `'2021-12'`. Then you can do something like this:

```py
pd.to_datetime('2021-12').to_period('Q') + 1
```

You can convert your date to this new format by simply inserting a `-` at index 4 of your string like so: `date[:4] + '-' + date[4:]`

This will take your date, convert it to quarters, and add 1 quarter.

Answer (score 2):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"Date": ['202112']})  # dummy data
df['next_quarter'] = pd.PeriodIndex(pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%Y%m'), freq='Q') + 1
print(df)
```

Output:

```
     Date next_quarter
0  202112  2022Q1
```

Note that column Date may be a string type but Quarter will be type *period*. You can convert it to a string if that's what you want.